# Cut part of a shapefile

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, multipart

This is my first time with QGIS and maybe it is an easy question but I can't figure out how to cut part of a layer to add it to another one.

In the image you can find (red circles) parts of a layer totally embedded in other layers. I would like to "cut" that parts and join/add to the surrounding layer.
[image]

I have tried to freehand selection tool but after defining the selected area the whole layer is selected. I just want to select the embedded piece, then create a new layer and add to the surrounding one.

Shapefiles have only one attribute, so I can't (do not want) to select by attribute but for region.

Shapefiles available in this [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/usxhng6inzjxtxl/qgis-shps.zip?dl=0) (Dropbox link)

I'm using QGIS 2.18.3 under Ubuntu 16.04.

As a novice any idea or advice is welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why you cannot choose the embedded piece alone is that your layer has multipart polygons. Try `Vector | Geometry Tools | Multipart to singleparts` to break them apart.

Or you may want to try an excellent plugin [Multipart Split](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/splitmultipart/). It enables us to split only aimed poygon and the splitted polygons are written directly onto the same layer, so your task can be done quickly and efficiently.

Comment: Used the `Multipart to singleparts` option, then I can select-cut-paste spatial objects.

Comment: @pacomet I am glad it worked out. Thanks for your feed back.